# Unable to publish infopath form to sharepoint 2013 due to Sandbox error

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-online

I am attempting to upload a form which contains fields for multiple digital signatures, however I recieve the following error when I hit publish:

'Sandboxed solutions are not published on the SharePoint server farm'.

This is strange considering I managed to publish the form successfully with a single signature applied across the form.

Answer (score 0):

I be supprised if this is your problem as well, but I was reciving the same error message while trying to publish an infopath form on a sharepoint server with a full or close to full system drive. Thought it might be worth checking. (The error, along with a host of other problems, went away after I cleared some space on the system drive)

Good Luck!